# pandas matching database with string keeping index of database

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database with strings and the index as below.

```
df0
idx name_id_code string_line_0
0 0.01 A
1 0.5 B
2 77.6 C
3 29.8 D
4 56.2 E
5 88.1000005 F
6 66.4000008 G
7 2.1 H
8 99 I
9 550.9999999 J


df1
idx string_line_1
0 A
1 F
2 J
3 G
4 D
```

Now, I want to match the df1 with df0, taking the values where df1 = df 0 but, keeping the index of df0 true as below

```
df_result name_id_code string_line_0
0 0.01 A
5 88.1000005 F
9 550.9999999 J
6 66.4000008 G
3 29.8 D
```

I tried with my code but it didnt work for string and only matching index

```
c = df0['name_id_code'] + ' (' + df0['string_line_0'].astype(str) + ')'
out = df1[df2['string_line_1'].isin(s)]
```

I also tried to keep simple just last column match like

```
c = df0['string_line_0'].astype(str) + ')'
out = df1[df1['string_line_1'].isin(s)]
```

but blank output.

Comment: Could you provide the df's content as a dict so we'll be able to use it inside our code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because is filtered `df0` DataFrame then is index values not changed if use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) by `df1['string_line_1'`, only order of columns is like in original `df0`:

```
out = df0[df0['string_line_0'].isin(df1['string_line_1'])]
print (out)
     name_id_code string_line_0
idx                            
0        0.010000             A
3       29.800000             D
5       88.100001             F
6       66.400001             G
9      551.000000             J
```

Or if use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) then for avoid lost `df0.index` is necessary add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
out = (df1.rename(columns={'string_line_1':'string_line_0'})
          .merge(df0.reset_index(), on='string_line_0'))
print (out)
  string_line_0  idx  name_id_code
0             A    0      0.010000
1             F    5     88.100001
2             J    9    551.000000
3             G    6     66.400001
4             D    3     29.800000
```

Similar solution, only same values in `string_line_0` and `string_line_1` columns:

```
out = (df1.merge(df0.reset_index(), left_on='string_line_1', right_on='string_line_0'))
print (out)
  string_line_1  idx  name_id_code string_line_0
0             A    0      0.010000             A
1             F    5     88.100001             F
2             J    9    551.000000             J
3             G    6     66.400001             G
4             D    3     29.800000             D
```

Comment: Your first solution: out =df1[df1['string_line_0'].isin(df0['string_line_1'])] can work only but, it is not taking the index of df0 as I need index of df0. with the sequence you used, taking wring values as there are also repeated strings and I need them with sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
out = df0.loc[(df0["string_line_0"].isin(df1["string_line_1"]))].copy()
out["string_line_0"] = pd.Categorical(out["string_line_0"], categories=df1["string_line_1"].unique())
out.sort_values(by=["string_line_0"], inplace=True)
```

The first line filters `df0` to just the rows where `string_line_0` is in the `string_line_1` column of `df1`.

The second line converts `string_line_0` in the output df to a Categorical feature, which is then custom sorted by the order of the values in df1

Comment: I need in output index of df0 as well. while the sequence of df1

Comment: Have updated my answer to show how to custom sort the output by the order of values in `df1`. The output will retain the index from `df0`

Comment: df1 = df0 with the index of df0, but the sequence required is df1